# Moving a <script> changes the result: why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<div style="text-align: justify">[Introduction text]</div> <br> <br> 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Vspoiler" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openPage('Vspoiler')">Vulgate version</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Cspoiler" onclick="openPage('Cspoiler')">Campbell version</a>
    </li> 
</ul> 
<div id="Vspoiler" class="tab-pane tabcontent active"><br> 
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="column" style="padding-left: 80px"> [Contents of col 1 of tab 1] </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="column" style="padding-left: 80px"> [Contents of col 2 of tab 2] </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> 
<div id="Cspoiler" class="tab-pane tabcontent"><br> 
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="column" style="padding-left: 80px"> [Contents of col 1 of tab 2] </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="column" style="padding-left: 80px"> [Contents of col 2 of tab 2] </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div> 
<script> 

    function openPage(pageName) { 
        var i, tabcontent; 
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent"); 
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) { 
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none"; 
        } 

        document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block"; 
    }

    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click(); 

</script>
```

In the above code, there is a  element at the end. If it is left there, the output is as desired. If moved to the top, the output changes, in that the contents of all the `tabcontents` panes (or whatever the best term to call them is) is shown upon loading, and only when an inactive tab is clicked do the contents of the others (in this case 1 but any others if there are more than 2 total) disappear. Why does that happen?

Note: This is a follow-up to this, and the code is mostly by @Bradley who answered there.

Comment: Can you organize that code better?

Comment: "element at the end" Do you mean the script tag?

Comment: @Daniel Oh damn. I copy-pasted, and my mobile thought it wise to get rid of linebreaks and indentation.  I have already eeited far too much HTML with my mobile today and my elbows are aching, so I will only do that tomorrow. But please feel free to beat me to it :).

Comment: @Sébastien I wrote `<script> element` but the "script", part was treated as HTML and gobbled up.

Comment: Your script needs HTML elements fully rendered (DOM built). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716680/2055998

Comment: JS scripts element contents are executed synchronously inline (unless configured otherwise). Any JS expression evaluated prior to "document ready" can only refer to elements *already* fully parsed (eg. opened *and* closed) in the *preceding HTML* markup being loaded. Moving the script location to the top has the `document.getElementById("defaultOpen")` being executed *before* the element is available to manipulate. This error does not occur when the script is at the bottom because the element has been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happens because the `script` run before `document` is `ready`. ( sync ). 
If you want to keep your `script` at the beginning of the `body`, or in head, use de `window.onload` function.

```
window.onload = function()
{ 
 // your code goes here
}
```

> My suggestion will be to place the `script` at the end of the body, also
>   the `bootstrap` and `jquery` libs, because those scripts will be fired
>   after the DOM is ready.